# how to insert the new incremental data(keeping old records) into delta lake table azure databricks table from Source snowflake table

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I am trying to insert the data incrementally from snowflake table to azure databricks delta lake table.

[image: snowflake table data and expected output in delta lake]

Existing table data

id   name   salary  dept           address   createdate   updateddate  enddate
1    aaa     5000   pharma         usa     08-23-2022   01-01-9999   01-01-9999
2    bbb     6000   mechanical     uk           08-23-2022  01-01-9999   01-01-9999
3    ccc     7000   pharma         singpare 08-23-2022   01-01-9999  01-01-9999

New data added to the table

id  name   salary   dept      address   createdate     updateddate   enddate
1   aa     5000     pharma    germany   08-24-2022     01-01-9999    01-01-9999
4   fff    8000     IT        finland   08-24-2022     01-01-9999    01-01-9999

Expected data in table

id  name  salary  dept        address   createdate  updateddate   enddate
1   aaa   5000    pharma      usa       08-23-2022   08-24-2022   08-24-2022
2   bbb   6000    mechanical  uk        08-23-2022   01-01-9999   01-01-9999
3   ccc   7000    pharma      singpare  08-23-2022   01-01-9999   01-01-9999
1   aa    5000    pharma      germany   08-24-2022   01-01-9999   01-01-9999
4   fff   8000    IT          finland   08-24-2022   01-01-9999   01-01-9999

Comment: Hey @bigdata techie, do you have snowflake table data as a dataframe in your databricks notebook?

Comment: Yes, I can load the snowflake table data into data frame

Comment: Doesn't work doing a simple INSERT?

Answer (score 1):

Try with a MERGE statement, this will update your matched rows and insert the unmatched. If your data is stored in memory as dataframe, then create a temporary view using:

```
snowflakedf.createOrReplaceTempView("<ALIAS>")
```

Then, in case your table primary key is the id and the name:

```
MERGE INTO <EXISTING_TABLE_NAME> AS T1 USING 
    (
        SELECT 
           id,
           name, 
           salary,
           dept,
           adress,
           createdate,
           date_format(from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(), "CET"),'yyyy-MM-dd') as updateddate,
           date_format(from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(), "CET"),'yyyy-MM-dd') as enddate
        FROM <ALIAS>
    ) AS TMP
ON T1.id= TMP.id AND T1.name = TMP.name 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  T1.createdate= TMP.createdate,
  T1.updateddate= TMP.updateddate,
  T1.enddate= TMP.enddate
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT *
```

For more information about how does it work check:

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-merge-into.html

If an insert better fits your problem try this:

```
INSERT INTO <EXISTING_TABLE_NAME> 
        SELECT 
           id,
           name, 
           salary,
           dept,
           adress,
           createdate,
           date_format(from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(), "CET"),'yyyy-MM-dd') as updateddate,
           date_format(from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(), "CET"),'yyyy-MM-dd') as enddate
        FROM <ALIAS>
```

Comment: After the initial full load  how we can pull the newly added data(incrementally) in the source snowflake to the data bricks table?

Comment: Does the edit help you? Is difficult for me to really understand which is your blocker.

Comment: every time when I run the data bricks notebook I need to process only new records from the source table. If any column value is changed for any existing record, we have to append that record with existing records along with the new records.

Comment: In this case you need to perform a MERGE.

Comment: Can we do Merge for both matched and not matched ?

Comment: Facing challenge with syntax to do Merge for both matched and not matched

Comment: Check if the edit works for you.

Comment: We should update only updated date and  end date columns of the existing record, we have to append the new record of the same id to the table( here we are maintaining the history of all records)  I attached a screenshot of sample data and expected output in the issue description

Comment: This is backwards. The final dataset does not indicate a `merge`, it indicates an `insert`. The OP's problem is that they can't identify changed records to pull out of the source

Comment: Check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MERGE` for loading data incrementally from  your *Snowflake table to Databricks delta lake table*.

- First create a view using the dataframe which is loaded using snowflake table data.
- Now create your delta lake table in databricks (IF NOT EXISTS) using your delta lake location.
- Since the snowflake data consists of records that are already inserted, you can extract the new records that need to be addressed (inserted).
- Create a MERGE statement with only matched condition to update the `updateddate` and `enddate` column when condition is matched.
- You can directly insert the rest of the records because the required updates are made, and we need to insert new data along with existing id (different values for other columns). This is the reason we created `req_snowflake_df`
- You can use the following code with required modifications to load data incrementally.

```
#create view with snowflake table data loaded into dataframe
df.createOrReplaceTempView("input_snowflake_df")


#only new data
df_new_data = spark.sql("select ip.* from input_snowflake_df as ip left join my_delta as d on d.id=ip.id and d.name=ip.name and d.salary=ip.salary and d.address=ip.address and d.createdate=ip.createdate where d.id is NULL")
df_new_data.show()

df_new_data.createOrReplaceTempView("req_snowflake_df")
```

```
%sql

MERGE into my_delta as d USING req_snowflake_df as ip
ON (d.id = ip.id and (d.name!=ip.name or d.salary!=ip.salary or d.dept!=ip.dept))
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET d.updateddate=ip.createdate, d.enddate=ip.createdate;

insert into my_delta select * from req_snowflake_df
```

The following are my output images for demonstration:

- Current snowflake table data, required new columns and my delta table records.

[image]

- After MERGE:
  [image]

Comment: after incremental load we should not modify the existing records in delta lake(we have to maintain the history of records) we should append the changed rows to the table similar to new rows.

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by append? Please provide an example of what you want to do if snowflake table data record already exists in delta lake.

Comment: I attached the screenshot of  table sample data and expected output data

Comment: So when a particular id already exists, for that id, you want to change `updateddate` and `enddate` values in delta lake table with the `createdate` value in snowflake table record and still insert that record. Is this right?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: Updated my answer. Check if it helps achieve your requirements.